# Unable to joint two geopandas data framesm due to 'rtree' error

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, geospatial, geopandas, r-tree

There are two shapefiles. And I have extracted those two data using geopandas file. and it was successful.

```
File 1 : 
zipfile_mobile = "zip://File Saved Location/2020-01-01_performance_mobile_tiles.zip"
mobile_tiles = gp.read_file(zipfile_mobile)

File : 2
zipfile = "zip://File Saved Location/tl_2019_us_county.zip"
counties = gp.read_file(zipfile)
```

[image]
[image]

Now I want to look for the intersection of those data. while run the following command I'm getting the error message as below.

```
ky_counties = counties.loc[counties['STATEFP'] == '21'].to_crs(4326)
```

But when I do the following error has occurred.

```
Spatial indexes require either `rtree` or `pygeos`. See installation instructions at https://geopandas.org/install.html
```

But already rtree has been installed.

[image]

Python: 3.9.1

Also, note that the following libraries are already imported.

```
import geopandas as gp
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from shapely.geometry import Point
from adjustText import adjust_text
import rtree
```

Comment: Which version of geopandas do you have? 0.8.1?

Comment: Yes, Geopandas 0.8.1

Answer (score 1):

After I remove ".to_crs(4326)" from the below code, then code execution succeeded.

```
ky_counties = counties.loc[counties['STATEFP'] == '21'].to_crs(4326)
```

The same CRS can often be referred to in many ways. For example, one of the most commonly used CRS is the WGS84 latitude-longitude projection. This can be referred to using the authority code "EPSG:4326".
It means no need for this conversion in this case.